# jQuery - set background image with brackets in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating elements based on an array named `result` and I want to dynamically add the background-image for each `item` from this array. The problem is that the current markup doesn't put the url in parenthesis so if my url has brackets the image doesn't get set.

How do I change the markup to put the url from `result[i].logo` in parenthesis to make it read my variable as a text string?

```
$(result).each(function (i, e) {
  var item =
    "<div style='background-image: url(" +
    result[i].logo +
    ");' background-color:" +
    result[i].color +
    "'></div>";
  $(item).appendTo(".list");
});
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] - include a couple of examples for `result`.  But otherwise your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zpr7xsgj/  so depends on values of `.logo`

Comment: Also you would need [`$.each(result,function() {})`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: What if you `console.log(result[i])`?

Comment: If the logo has brackets in it's url path name the background image doesn't set. I need to change the markup so that the url is read as url("") instead of just url()

Comment: Ah - @N.K. had this, but edited and deleted their answer:  `background-image: url(\"" + results[i].logo + "\");`

Comment: @freedomn-m That's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have quote issues and likely meant to use the array specific

[`$.each(result, function() {})`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

because [`$(selector).each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is meant to iterate over jQuery objects

I suggest instead this which also wraps the logo in quotes

```
$(".list").html(
   result
   .map(res => `<div style="background-image: url('${res.logo}'); background-color: ${res.color}"></div>`)
   .join("")
);
```

---

To improve your version, make sure the quotes are correct. I prefer double quotes around html attributes

```js
var item =
  '<div style="background-image: url(\'' +
  result[i].logo +
  '\'); background-color:' +
  result[i].color +
  '></div>';
```

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer `$.each(arr, function()..` over `$(arr).each(function()...`  - both should be equivalent other than potential micro-optimisation (one way or other, not going to check).

Comment: In my opinion and to my recollection , [`$(selector).each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is to iterate over jQuery objects and [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) which I never use, is for any JS  array or object. Perhaps now you can use either for arrays, but that is really confusing

Comment: Thanks, I've been using `$(arr).each(...` for years, never had an issue, the fiddle I created for this question works fine.   Had another look at the jquery docs (if in doubt, check the docs...) and it states *The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, **exclusively**, over a jQuery object.* - strange that it works when they say themselves it shouldn't!

Comment: I have used `arr.each` for as long as I could, and would NEVER use `$.each` when JS has a built-in iterator

Comment: Yes, no need for jquery array loop here.  I guess I'm still old school and haven't caught up with these new fangled js methods :)  It's *only* [been available](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_foreach) for 10 years - if it wasn't in IE6, I don't know it :D